# What is the difference between "how much is it","how much does that cost" and "what is the cost of that item?"?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, difference

If I want to ask the value of an item could I use the sentences below?

> 1 how much is it
>
> 2 how much does that cost
>
> 3 what is the cost of that item?

If not, then what is the difference between 1,2 and 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say "How much is **it**?" about something that has already been mentioned, example:

I like that hat. How much is it?.

You can say "How much is **that**?" or "How much does **that** item cost?" about something that you indicate (possibly by pointing at it). "How much is it/that?" and "How much does it/that cost?" are ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: How do I ask the total that I have to pay for example after shopping in the supermarket?

Comment: "How much is it altogether?" is possible. Also "How much is it?" where "it" is the total price.